# Empty text box validation jQuery

Tags: jquery, forms, validation, jquery-mobile

I have 3 text fields where data can be added to a table, however, I can submit data to the table even if all the fields are empty, can this form of validation be used with plain jQuery or must it be used with a plugin?.

Comment: Why not jQuery as you anyway use it for the plugin?

Comment: jQuery also. Can this be done without a plugin?

Comment: Of course it can be. So, if the value is empty, you do no want to execute the case, just skip it?

Comment: OK, I'll come up with something soon.

Answer (score 0):

You can either explicitly check them all:

```
// at least one is empty
if ($('#myId_1').val() == '' || $('$myId_2').val() == '') {
    alert('Oops! Please fill them all!');
}
// all are empty
if ($('#myId_1').val() == '' && $('$myId_2').val() == '') {
    alert('Oops! Please fill at least one!');
}
```

Or if you want to support a variable number of fields for the future, something like this can work:

```
var invalid = false;
$('#table tr input:text').each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == '') {
        invalid = true;
        return false;
    }
});

if (invalid)
    alert('Fill all the fields please!');
```

[Here's a working example.](http://jsfiddle.net/2nU7u/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with jQuery, without using any additional plugin.
This script will do the trick. Note that it's going through all the your text fields. I also added a visual confirmation for the user (green border == OK, red border == 'not OK').

Hope you can use it.

```
$('#yourSubmitButtonId').click(function(){
    var isValid = 1;
    $('input:text').each(function(){
        if($(this).val() == ''){
            $(this).css('border','1px solid red');
            isValid = 0;
            }
        else{
            $(this).css('border','1px solid green');
            }
        });

    if(isValid == 0){
        alert('Please enter content to all text fields');
        return false;
        }

    //if valid then do something
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

> "If any of the boxes are empty, I want an alert and dont want the
>   function 'AddScore' to be called"

So, here we go. You just need to find out if the number of filled inputs are less than the total number of inputs. So, slightly change your function as below:

```
function AddScore() {
    var totalInputs = $('div[data-role="fieldcontain"] input:text').length;
    var nonEmptyInputs = $('div[data-role="fieldcontain"] input:text').filter(function(){return $.trim($(this).val()) !== ""}).length;
    if (nonEmptyInputs < totalInputs) {
        alert ("You've not filled all the boxes");
        return; //stop execution
    }
    //rest of the code
    var jqTableBody = $('#myTable tbody');
    ....
    ....
```

Comment: In my full example I have duplicates of the forms, obviously with different ID's and Names, but they have the same 'field contain', would I need to give the 'field contain' an ID for al forms to work?.

Comment: I am going to use a plug in for this issue, from advice from a friend I learnt how the plug in makes life easier, thank you anyways.

Comment: @user3464571, yes. and id or class would be good. For instance, change <div data-role="fieldcontain"> to <div class="section2" data-role="fieldcontain"> then instead of div[data-role="fieldcontain"] use div.section2

Comment: @user3464571, right, whatever suits your needs. You could have saved us some time though.